# Gameanalytics, days since install/session number filter

Tags: gameanalytics

In "look up metrics” I’m trying to know how my players improve in playing my game.

I have the score (both as desing event and progression, just to try) and in look up metrics I try to “filter” with session number or days since install but, even if I group by Dimension, this doesn’t produce any result. 
For instance if I do the same but with device filter it shows me the right histogram with score's mean per device.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the customer care:

> The session filter works only on core metrics at this point (like DAU). We hope to make this filter compatible with custom metrics as well but this might take time as we first need to include this improvement to our roadmap and then evaluate it by comparing it with our other tasks. As a result, there is no ETA on making a release.
>
> I would recommend you to download the raw data (go to "Export data" in the settings of the game) and perform an analysis on your own for this sort of "per user" analysis. You should be able to create stats per user. GA does not do this since your game can reach millions of users and there's no way you can plot this amount of entries in a browser.